# What is the best way to determine if table already has record with specific ID?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have a short question. Im my current project I'm using LINQ-to-SQl. That is the best way to determine if table has record with specific ID?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to know if it exists, then perhaps:

```
var exists = db.SomeTable.Any(row => row.Id == id);
```

If you want the row (or `null` if it doesn't exist), then:

```
var row = db.SomeTable.FirstOrDefault(row => row.Id == id);
```

actually, in .NET 3.5 there is arguably [a benefit](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/362313/linq-to-sql-still-roundtrips-for-id-lookups-3-5sp1) to using:

```
var row = db.SomeTable.Where(row => row.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

but this is fixed in 4.0 and both work the same. The difference is that in 3.5SP, `FirstOrDefault(predicate)` doesn't check the identity-manager, so it would hit the db even if it already knows about the row you asked for (because it has it in-memory).